# How do I find the P-value using H1 and a Ztest or Ttest value

Tags: statistics

My questions go something like this: Use the given information to find the p-value

A) With $H_1: p = 0.0707$ with $Z_{test} = 3.37$

B) With $H_1 : p > 72$, with $Z_{test} = 2.91$

C) With $ H_1: μ < 72, \, n = 61$, and $t_{test} = -2.92$

D) With two-tailed test with $n = 31$ and $t_{test} = 1.92$

This is the only data provided for each question so as you can see there is no confidence interval or rejecting the null hypothesis, just finding out the p-value.

I do have Z table and T table charts

Answer (score 0):

A) You have two sided alternative, hence $P.value = P(|Z|>3.37)$, which means $P.value = P(Z>3.37)+P(Z<-3.37)$, where $Z\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

B)  One sided alternative $P.value = P(Z>2.91)$.

C) $P.value = P(T_{61-1}<-2.92)$.

D) $P.value = P(|T_{31-1}|>1.92)$. Where $60$ and $30$ are the degrees of freedom of the corresponding $t$ distribution, hence you can use tables to find the corresponding probability.